# php class inheritance $this->... is undefined?

Tags: php

EDIT: solved, I was using private instead of protected properties in the Controller class.

I'm getting an error when trying to use a property from a class im inheriting. My Controller class looks like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Http\Request;
use Http\Response;
use App\Templates\Renderer;

class Controller{
    private $request;
    private $response;
    private $renderer;

    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response, Renderer $renderer){
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
    }
}
```

and the Pages class that I'm extending from looks like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\Book;


class Pages extends Controller{

    public function index(){
        $book = new Book;
        $book->title = 'test';
        // $book->save();
        // echo 'Book created';
        $html = $this->renderer->render('index');
        $this->response->setContent($html);
    }
}
```

And the error im getting looks like this

```
Undefined property: App\Controllers\Pages::$renderer
```

Comment: Private   private $renderer;???

Comment: you should change the visibility of your fields to `protected` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: OMG how did I not see this!? changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the visibility of your `$renderer` field from `private` to `protected`.

And that's because

- **private** fields/functions can be accessed only from their own classes
- **public** fields/functions can be accessed from anywhere
- **protected** fields/functions can be accessed from all classes that extend current class including the parent class

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer Diego!